# Relationship in a sequence of arcsin functions

Tags: trigonometry

Does any relationship exist in the series $(2/\pi) \arcsin \sqrt{1/2}$, $(2/\pi)\arcsin\sqrt{(1/2)^2}$, $(2/\pi)\arcsin\sqrt{(1/2)^3}$, $(2/\pi)\arcsin\sqrt{(1/2)^4}$ etc?

Comment: What type of relationship and why would you expect one?

Comment: Some kind of recursive relationship between the consecutive elements, for example element 3 is a function of elements 1 and 2.

Comment: Please be more precise about what types of functions you would accept.  For example, if $a_1$ is the first one and $a_3$ is the third one, then $a_3=(2/\pi)\arcsin((\sin((\pi/2)a_1)^2)$.

Comment: The power in my previous comment should be $3$, not $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for something like a ratio, sum etc that allows to quickly calculate the elements recursively.

Comment: You seemed to state that the third expression is a combination of the first two expressions.  Can you provide the relationship that you know?